# Excel: How to make cell blank if formula returns an error or a number less than 0 or greater than 1?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am working on an Excel spreadsheet and want to make my formulas return a blank cell if the formula returns an error, a number less than 0, or a number greater than 1. I cannot get my head wrapped around how to construct this IF statement. Here is my current formula:

P9=IF(AVERAGE(C9:O9)<0.001,"",AVERAGE(C9:O9)-1)/4

Q9=IF(B9<1,"",(B9-1)*P9/4)

Comment: If the formula in this cell (Q9) returns an error, I want it to return "", but I also want it to return "" if 1>B9>5, or if 1>AVERAGE(C9:09)>5. Sorry if I'm not explaining it well, it is tough to explain without showing. My rating scale in B9:09 is 1-5, and I'm subtracting 1 and dividing by 4 to convert to a decimal.

Comment: Alternatively, as I said in my original description, I could make my constraint 0>Q9>1, if that would be easier. I don't use IF statements much.

Comment: Then this should work for you: `=IFERROR(IF(OR(ISERROR(Q9),AND(B9>1,B9<5),AND(AVERAGE(C9:09)>1,AVERAGE(C9:09)<5)),"",your result),"")`.

Comment: Excel tells me there is a mistake in the formula. Did I add an extra parenthesis somewhere?=IFERROR(IF(OR(ISERROR(Q9),AND(B9>1,B9<5),AND(AVERAGE(C9:09)‌​>1,AVERAGE(C9:09)<5)‌​),"",(B9-1)*P9/4),"")

Comment: Try this: `=IFERROR(IF(OR(ISERROR(Q9),AND(B9>1,B9<5),AND(AVERAGE(C9:O9)>1,AVERAGE(C9:O9)<5)),"",(B9-1)*P9/4),"")`

Comment: It looks like Excel is not recognizing anything after the second "AVERAGE" function bolded below. I checked if the #0 was used in place of the letter O, and it was not. =IFERROR(IF(OR(ISERROR(Q9),AND(B9>1,B9<5),AND(AVERAGE(C9:O9)‌​>1,**AVERAGE(C9:O9)<5)‌​),"",(B9-1)*P9/4),""‌​)**

Comment: I had the same issue when I tried yours.  I had to retype everything in order for this formula to work.  A trick is when you type in your formula, you can point the cursor to the function you want to see and click the `fx` icon next to formula bar to bring up the Function Arguments window to see if what you have typed is valid or not.  I will say retype everything in a little by little.  Bad that this happened.

Comment: BTW, I just enter the formula into the answer box and copied it to Excel then it worked (didn't work when I copied from comment).  Try that and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the iferror function: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-iferror-function

basically

```
iferror(if(check for zero or one,"",somethingElse),"")
```

slightly easier to read maybe

```
A = a statement checking if something is zero or one
B = a placeholder value
C = blank = "" or something similar

iferror(if(A,B,C),C)
```

Comment: So I need to start my function with IFERROR? I tried something like the following but it didn't work. =IF(1>B9>5, "", IF(1>SUM(C9:O9)>65, "", IFERROR((B9-1)*P9/4, "", (B9-1)*P9/4)))

Comment: you're right- you need to start with iferror; will add more info to my answer in a second

Answer (score 0):

Try this one here:

`=IFERROR(IF(OR(ISERROR(Q9),AND(B9>1,B9<5),AND(AVERAGE(C9:O9)>1,AVERAGE(C9:O9)<5)),"",(B9-1)*P9/4),"")`